# Using curl in google colab to download TTF file, results in unknown file format

Tags: curl, python-imaging-library, google-colaboratory

I'm finalizing a google Colab that processes and labels some images. The bulk of the work is done, however i'm trying to fetch a TTF file for use in labeling and running into some odd behavior.

I've used the following to download the file:

`!curl https://github.com/USERNAME/REPO/raw/master/src/arial.ttf -o src/arial.ttf`

but later when trying to use it with ImageDraw I get an unknown file type error:

`OSError: unknown file format`

When hand placing the file into the correct folder, everything processes as expected. Additionally, after pulling the file retrieved by curl it no longer functions locally. Given that, I'm fairly confident retrieving it with curl is somehow changing/corrupting the file.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I was just having the same exact issue.  What I ended up doing was removing the need to store it as a file and letting `ImageFont.truetype` read directly from the url stream, as such:

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
url = 'https://github.com/googlefonts/josefinsans/blob/master/fonts/ttf/JosefinSans-Regular.ttf?raw=true'
font = ImageFont.truetype(urlopen(url), size=10)
```

Another thing to note is the addition of `?raw=true` on the url to ensure the file is returned instead of a github decorated page (even with that I was having issues saving the ttf file *locally* on google colab)